# Rails 4 datatable ajax routing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

Im trying to use the sample code from -- > https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I am just playing around with the sample in my existing project as a demo. All my DataTable methods are in a tests.js class in assets/javascript

My controller is not doing anything right now until I hook this up to mongo for real but right now I want to use that objects.txt son file to play around with the table to get it correct.  Im not sure what route I need since that document.ready method is in tests.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#queryone_table').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/rails/public/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
```

Routing Error

Started GET "/rails/public/objects.txt?_=1479232156328" for ::1 at 2016-11-15 12:49:17 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rails/public/objects.txt"):

Comment: Does the file exist? I know it sounds a stupid question, but, The error said that the file does not exist. If exist, where are you saving it?

Comment: It does exist in my public folder.  What is throwing me off is I do not really have anything in my controller doing work because I just want my datable to load in my view with that JSON data just like the demo page.  Im unsure how I would route that.  I'm running locally with web brick as this is just a demo project.

Comment: If that file is in public/rails/public/objects.txt it should work without any extra route or controller, maybe is a problem with that route.

Comment: I thought because the datable javascript file was essentially loading the file that was my issue. --> var table = $('#queryone_table').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/rails/public/objects.txt",          so my controller right now does nothing. I just want to load my table with different JSON files to play with the structure of my JSON.

Comment: Got it.  My mistake.  It was as simple as using just /objects  instead of the full path.  100% my bad

Comment: Great, could you poster as an answer? so we can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the full path /rails/public/objects.txt"  all I needed to do was /objects.txt

my bad